# Pagination doesn't work when offset is set in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming

Can anyone explain me why my pagination is not working?
Please have a look at the code below

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'offset' => '1',
    'page' => $page,
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
);

query_posts($args);
$i = 1;
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

?>
```

When I comment or remove `'offset' => '1'` pagination works.
Is there any alternative way for offset?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: can you please include query_posts function as well as have posts Just from an array its really difficult to say whats going on

Comment: well those are WordPress functions, you can see them in the following links: 
query_post ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/ )
have_posts ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_posts/ )

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Please read this it describes the signature of the parameter `$args` in your case

Comment: Offsets breaking pagination is a well known issue. https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $current_page = get_query_var('paged');
    $current_page = max( 1, $current_page );
    $per_page = 2;
    $offset_start = 1;
    $offset = ( $current_page - 1 ) * $per_page + $offset_start;

    $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'podcast',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
        'offset' => $offset,
        'paged' => $current_page,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $total_rows = max( 0, $query->found_posts - $offset_start );
    $total_pages = ceil( $total_rows / $per_page );
?>

<?php if($query->have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'total'   => $total_pages,
            'current' => $current_page,
            'next_text'=> "Next",
            'prev_text'=> "Prev",
        ));
    ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**This works for me.**

Comment: Please add comments and explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination) article explains how to use WordPress's `offset` value in your queries without breaking WordPress's built-in pagination.

You will need to write some additional code to manually handle pagination; you need to detect whether a loop has additional pages and then dynamically calculate the appropriate offset for the current page.

You'll use the `pre_get_posts` hook built into WordPress. See the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).